# Check if both strings are empty not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have a conditional if check on a webform on which ajax (and php) is doing the submit work.

```
if(empty($name) or empty($message))
{
do something
}
```

The above is working if one of the 2 strings is empty.I want to add to the above

```
  or (empty($name) and empty($message))
```

for checking if both strings are empty but in someway its not working!I want to make sure all 3 senarios are covered,Name empty or Message empty or both empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: The first condition will "do something" if both is empty.  "or" is not exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check that both `$name` and `$message` is not blank, than true

```
if($name != '' &&  $message != '') {
  //Do something
}
```

If you use this, this will check if any 1 field is empty than the condition is true

```
if($name == '' || $message == '') {
  //Do something
}
```

If you use this, this will be true if both are empty

```
if($name == '' && $message == '') {
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: @Theodoros80 whhat you exactly need?

Comment: Told at the description.Check if a webform have the name and message values filed and not empty.

Comment: that also depends on what code you are executing in the condition..I've given you three options read it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Replace "or" with "||". Example:

```
if (empty($name) || empty($message))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`or` means "If either condition is true", not "If exactly one condition is true".

The code you have already covers your requirement.